# Injecting a POJO class from an EJB jar into an EJB in a different EJB jar

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

Given I have two EJB jars in an ear: A.jar and B.jar. Can I inject a utility class `Autil` that is not an EJB, just a POJO from A.jar into an EJB that is in B.jar using CDI? I cannot find this clearly in the Java EE specs. (Btw. I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1)

**Note:** Of course I could try it (and already had meanwhile) but that way I could only check it with specific AS and I would like to know what the spec says about it because I am trying to be vendor neutral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using GlassFish do yourself a favor and use 3.1.2.2. Next, yes you should be able to do that just fine. Make sure both jars have META-INF/beans.xml as well as your web app (WEB-INF/beans.xml)

Comment: Do you know about bugs fixed in that version related to my question?

Comment: I don't know of the bug fixes, but I'm pretty sure they're using a more current version of Weld. I doubt you'll have issues, the main thing is to remember to have the beans.xml in both jars.